# IOS Swift Mailgun not sending email

Tags: ios, swift, mailgun

I am trying to send Email using MailGun api with Swift. I created and activate free account with mailgun. Installed pod.

[cocoapods mailgun pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20mailgu)

If I press button I am getting message "Email was sent" but I am not receiving this email, nor it is displays in mailgun "Logs" or "Reporting".

I have also added and verified my personal e-mail to "Authorized Recipients"

I tied to run on IOS simulator and actual devices no luck.

```
   @IBAction func dddd(_ sender: Any) {

    let mailgun = MailgunAPI(apiKey: "key-<my_key from mailgun>, clientDomain: "sandboxe437***********.mailgun.org")

    mailgun.sendEmail(to: "me@mail.com", from: "Test User <myemail@mail.com", subject: "This is a test15", bodyHTML: "<b>test<b>") { mailgunResult in

        if mailgunResult.success{
            print("Email was sent")
        }else{
            print("error")
        }

}
```

Any word of advise what did I missed?

Thank you,

Stalker

Answer (score 3):

@Stalker, your `from` parameter does not have a closing `>`. I hope you have seen it.
If you are already using **Alamofire** for your network requests then no need for this extra dependency `mailgun pod`:

## Swift 3.2

```
 import Alamofire
    
    let parameters = [
                   "from": "sender@whatyouwant.com",
                     "to": "anyRecipient@example.com",
                "subject": "Subject of the email",
                   "text": "This is the body of the email."]
    let header = [
            "Authorization": "Basic YOUR-BASE64ENCODED-KEY",
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

    let url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR-DOMAIN/messages"
    Alamofire.request(url,
                   method: .post,
               parameters: parameters,
                 encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                  headers: header)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("Response: \(response)")
                }
```

In the header, you have to replace `YOUR-BASE64ENCODED-KEY` with the base64 encoded string of "API:YOUR-SECRET-API-KEY" where `YOUR-SECRET-API-KEY`is found on your Mailgun dashboard.

In the URL you also replace `YOUR-DOMAIN` with your Mailgun domain.

With that you should be good to go and send emails through Mailgun.