# Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type 'HTTPHeaders?'

Tags: swift, alamofire, mailgun

I´m trying to send mail from my iOS app with `Mailgun` and `Alarmofire` I found [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170799/ios-swift-mailgun-not-sending-email) but `Xcode` generates error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument
>   type 'HTTPHeaders?'

Code:

```
let parameters = [
                   "from": "sender@whatyouwant.com",
                     "to": "anyRecipient@example.com",
                "subject": "Subject of the email",
                   "text": "This is the body of the email."]
    let header = [
            "Authorization": "Basic MY-API-KEY",
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

    let url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY-DOMAIN/messages"
    Alamofire.request(url,
                   method: .post,
               parameters: parameters,
                 encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                  headers: header)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("Response: \(response)")
                }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set the type explicitly.

```swift
let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic MY-API-KEY",
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]
```

Comment: Better yet, use the strongly typed versions of those headers: `.authorization("Basic MY-API-KY)` and `.contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`. And you don't need to set a content type, the parameter encoding / encoder will do that for you.

Comment: Yeap, this happened to the solution for the older definition with [String: String].. same but the type should be HTTP headers

Answer (score 1):

To modify existing code create Dictionary exention to cast from [String: String] to HTTPHeaders.

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == String {
    func toHeader() -> HTTPHeaders {
        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]
        for (key, value) in self  {
            headers.add(name: key, value: value)
        }
        return headers
    }
}
```

and use this extention to cast it.

```
AF.request(url, method: requestMethod, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default ,headers: header?.toHeader())
```